Hollywood horrror movie with kids and school van

I'm looking for a mystery/horror Hollywood movie.
The film was in colour.
I am not sure about the release date.
The main characters I remember are a bunch of kids met by a series of
mysterious events revolving around a school bus filled with many kids
which fell into a lake.
In the initial part of the movie, the school bus event is shown as
just a myth or story but, later, these kids discover the place where
the bus accident happened.
One more thing remember is that these kids use a moving lift like
thing for up and down transport to this accident site.
I remember some events related to Christmas also, which I cannot
remember much precisely.

What movie is this?

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question.

I know it's been answered but it sounds like a Jack Handy's Fuzzy Memories version of The Sweet Hereafter. ;)

It's Trick 'r Treat, a 2007 American-Canadian anthology horror film written and directed by Michael Dougherty. It centers on four Halloween-related horror stories.
The story you are describing is The School Bus Massacre Revisited
Wikipedia

Four trick-or-treaters seen earlier scour the neighborhood, collecting
  jack-o'-lanterns. They stop at the home of schoolmate Rhonda, said to
  be a savant. They ask for one of her jack-o'-lanterns and invite
  Rhonda to a quarry. When they arrive, the group's leader, Macy, claims
  it is the site of "The Halloween School Bus Massacre", a local legend.
According to Macy, 30 years ago, the bus was carrying 4 mentally
  challenged and disturbed boys and 4 mentally challenged and disturbed
  girls (A total of 8 mentally challenged and mentally disturbed
  children), clad in freakish Halloween costumes and so deranged that
  they had to be chained to their seats. The driver had been paid by
  their parents to drive the bus into a lake at the bottom of the
  quarry, and the bus and bodies were never recovered. The eight
  jack-o'-lanterns collected are meant as an offering to the eight souls
  who died.
They take a rickety elevator to the bottom of the quarry where the
  teens seem to be attacked by water-drenched figures in chains. It
  turns out to be a cruel prank to scare Rhonda. However, when Macy
  kicks a jack-o'-lantern into the lake, the eight dead children rise
  up. The other teens beg Rhonda to let them in the elevator, but she
  ascends with the jack-o'-lanterns instead.







Clip:Trick 'R Treat: The halloween school bus massacre
